# org.openqaをインポートして使うことができない

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

org.openqaをインポートして使うことができず、下記のようにnameエラーになってしまいます。

```
import org.openqa


No module named 'org'
```

-試したこと
・pythonを対話シェルにして、ひとつひとつ再確認致しまたが結果は一緒でした
・似たような事例を探してみましたが、同じような事例は発見できませんでした

ご教授いただけば幸いです、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

Java向けの名前空間をPythonで使おうとしているということですか？
何を参考にして何をやろうとされていますか？

---

追記します。

`org.openqa` はJavaバインディングでの名前空間です。
あなたが参考にしているのはJava向けの記述です。Pythonバインディングでは使えません。
Python向けの記述を参考にしてください。

Pythonバインディングでは `selenium` モジュールを利用します。
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium
`<select>` 要素の操作には `selenium.webdriver.support.ui` モジュールの `Select` クラスを使用します。
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms

Comment: hiroshitoda様。コメントいただきありがとうございます。プルダウン(select要素)の選択は、clickメソッドでも可能ですが、コードが複雑になるためこちらのクラスを使用するのがおすすめと本に記載がありましたので、それに従っている次第でございます。わたしの認識不足だとは思うのですが、Pythonではそもそも使えないということでしょうか?

Comment: hiroshitoda様。追記をいただきありがとうございます。htb様、cubick様コメントいただきありがとうございます。上記のコメントを参考にさせていただき、取り組んだ結果をここに反映させていただきたいと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。